# 'this' reference to the function caller in Lua

Tags: function, lua

I'm wondering how to get a `this` reference inside a Lua function. I'm used to having a `this` reference inside a function (like in JavaScript) that refers to the object that is calling it.

For example, in JavaScript:

```
var person = {
    'name' : 'Saucy Jack',
    'speak' : function() {
        console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
    };
};
```

In that example, when `person.speak()` is called, `this` in the function body will reference `person` (which is calling the function). How can I get a reference to `this` in a Lua function?

For example, that same `person` object in Lua:

```
local person = {
    name = 'Saucy Jack',
    speak = function() 
        print("Hi, my name is " + self.name);
    end
};
```

From what I understand in Lua, `self` is used instead of `this`, but I can't get the above example to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the semi-colons aren't required at all.

Next, you'd need to define the function outside of the table's body for implicit call using `self`.

And, string concatenation is done using `..` and not `+`

```
local person = {
    name = 'Saucy Jack',
}
function person:speak()  -- or function person.speak(self)
    print("Hi, my name is "..self.name)
end
```

Here's a [working codepad sample](http://codepad.org/IT3UxpcQ).

Comment: Actually, you can use self implicitly in a call but explicitly in a function definition: 'speak = function(self) 
        print("Hi, my name is " + self.name);
    end'

Answer (score 0):

```
local person = {
name = 'Saucy Jack',
speak = function(self) 
    print("Hi, my name is " .. self.name);
end
};
person:speak()
```

http://codepad.org/eXwWNKme 
welcome to corona irc

Comment: -1; Explain why he needs to declare `self` in this case.